# ASP.Net Added Form Authentication now not showing domain/username

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I'm trying to record the logged in username and domian of a user when they submit a form. This worked fine until i added form authentication to the rest of the site.

I set a label to update the text on page load like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    UserN.Text = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
End Sub
```

...And as i say, this worked perfectly (showed Domain/Username).

Now i added form authentication which allows users to access just two pages so they can fill out the form. This was done in my web.config like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
    <forms name=".FILEAPP" loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>

  </system.web>

<location path="default.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<location path="PWForm.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Since adding this, it shows a blank where the Domain/Username used to be when not logged in and the logged in name if i log in.

So my question is - how do i show the domain login name while using form authentication for the rest of the site?

Thanks all!

Comment: I thought i nearly had it when i tried this:

    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

but no, it loads the server credentials :-(

Answer (score 0):

Now that you are using Forms Authentication, you should be able to use the built in [`Page.User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) field to read the logged in user's info:

```
UserN.Text = Page.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. I've just changed this and it's showing the username of the person that is logged in, not their domain name and network username. Is there anything else i can try? Thanks

Comment: @BenWilliams Using Forms Auth, you're not going to get the user's domain - you're going to get how they signed in to the web forms app.  You must have been using Windows Auth before.